# Group by and change the value if one of the value is null from similar group of data

Tags: sql

problem: There are two columns. column1(Tasks) and column2(User). column 1 might have some similar data(Tasks) and column 2 have true and false based on the user is assigned to that task or not.

I want is, In column 1 same tasks need to be group by first and check whether a user is assigned to all those same tasks or not, if one of the tasks is null from same tasks then it should return false.

```html
example : Table 

Value                               |PrimaryOwnerId
_______________________________________________________________________
EVP-RP&P                           |  null
Execution Coordinator                   |  null
Execution Coordinator                   |  2
Inspection Lead                           |  null
Instrument, Electrical, and Analyzer      |  null
Logistics                           |  1
Logistics                           |  1
Operations                           |  null
Planning                           |  4

Output table should look like :

Value                               |PrimaryOwnerId
_______________________________________________________________________
EVP-RP&P                           |  False
Execution Coordinator                   |  False
Inspection Lead                           |  False
Instrument, Electrical, and Analyzer      |  False
Logistics                           |  True
Operations                           |  False
Planning                           |  True
```

I am using this query.

```html
select CraftName AS value,
case 
   when PrimaryOwnerID is Null 
       Then 'true'
       else 'flase'
       End as PrimaryOwnerID
        FROM EventTasks AS et
                          INNER JOIN EventMileStones AS em ON em.EventMileStoneID = et.EventMileStoneID
                          INNER JOIN LocationTasks AS lt ON lt.LocationTaskID = et.LocationTaskID
                          INNER JOIN Crafts AS c ON c.ID = lt.CraftID
                     WHERE ProjectID = 4
                     group by CraftName, PrimaryOwnerID
```

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thank you, Next time I will make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not mentioned the database name, This following logic will work in most of the database-

```
SELECT Value,
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN  PrimaryOwnerId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'False' 
    ELSE 'True' 
END
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Value
```

As per your logic, Planning should get "True" as no null is assigned to this value but you shown "False" in your sample output data.